# requestAVAssetForVideo seems to hang when fetching some videos

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having some issues with fetching videos using `requestAVAssetForVideo`. It seems to be that when fetching some videos the `dispatch_async` never gets called, on other videos it is called and works as expected. Can someone spot what the issue might be?

```
- (void)videoSelected:(long)selectedVideoIndex {

    PHAsset *selectedVideo = [self.allVideos objectAtIndex:selectedVideoIndex];

    PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
    options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;


    self.movieInformation = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:selectedVideo options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
        // Use the AVAsset avAsset

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self loadingScreen];
             [self loadTheVideo:avAsset];
        });

    }];



}
```

**UPDATE**
It seems to be that when I run the same videos using the Photos app they also hang as well and the spinner keeps going.  Is there are way to add a timeout property that gets called when a video fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay is normal for videos/images that are stored in **iCloud**. If you have enabled iCloud backup and enabled **Optimize Storage** in phone's settings, your iPhone will backup videos and images to iCloud and maintains lower resolution of images and only thumbnails for videos and fetches them from iCloud on demand.
`networkAccessAllowed` in your code is responsible for fetching videos or images from iCloud. If it is `OFF`, iOS will not bother about items stored in iCloud - it will only fetch what's local in your device.